# how to accommodate default values for parent table In database design using EF 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I have following tables (Its not actually accessories but I am using it as an analogy),

```
- Accessories {AccessoriesId, Name, other accessory related attributes...}
  -  ClientAccessories (ClientAccessoryId, AccessoriesId, ***CLIENTID***, LastModified, CreatedDate, Username, isDeleted)
  -  EmployeeAccessories (EmployeeAccessoryId, AccessoriesId, ***EMPLOYEEID***, LastModified, CreatedDate, Username, isDeleted)
```

Now problem is that each Employee and each client will get a set of default accessories, which they can delete/update as well, which will set a flag in there specific table. They will add there own accessories as well in future.

I am not sure about if this is a valid design and how to start implementing it with EF 6 code first.

Comment: You could use inheritance for Accessories https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

wherever you want to add a client you can write

```
var client = new client
{
//assign your attribute
ClientAccessories = new ClientAccessories[] 
                    {   
                            new ClientAccessories {
                                //....
                                AccessoriesId = //id of dafualt accessories
                            },
                            new ClientAccessories {
                                //....
                                AccessoriesId = //id of dafualt accessories
                            }
                            //...
                    }
//.....
}

 context.clients.add(client);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Add all default accessories before any insert.
like this. And you can call AddDefaultAccessories method before any insert.

```cs
public void AddDefaultAccessories(Employee emp)
        {
            var defaultAcc1 = new Accessories();
            var defaultAcc2 = new Accessories();
            var defaultAcc3 = new Accessories();
            emp.Accessories.Add(defaultAcc1);
            emp.Accessories.Add(defaultAcc2);
            emp.Accessories.Add(defaultAcc3);
        }
```